# plugin woo-commerce, No Author of a product

Tags: wordpress

I hope everything is good with you.
Please,
I installed a plugin woo-commerce for wordpress.
When I create a product , I don't see any Author of a product,
Please, How can i add Author to each product ?

Best regards

A.J.

Comment: Check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74054/woocommerce-assign-an-author-to-a-product

Comment: WOW, Very nice. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress, each post or custom post(WooCommerce product) has an author. If you want to display the product author on 'Products' page, copy and paste the following code in your functions.php file.

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'wdm_columns_head');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'wdm_columns_content', 10, 2);

function wdm_columns_head($defaults) {
    $defaults['Author'] = 'Author';
    return $defaults;
}

function wdm_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'Author') {
        $post_featured_image = get_the_author($post_ID);
        if ($post_featured_image) {
            echo $post_featured_image;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, for your feedback. I did it, but ...., please check:http://grab.by/Ayk0

Comment: Thank you so much Guys, I fixed my issue by your support.